# Why memory leaks if i add vector<int> to class that I use to create an array by new[]

Tags: c++, vector, memory-leaks, address-sanitizer

I wrote this code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
using namespace std;

class G {
public:
    vector<int> v = {1};
};

int main() {
    G* t = new G[5];
    new (t) G();
    delete [] t;
}
```

I compile this by this way:

```
clang++ -std=c++20 -fsanitize=address b.cpp -o main -Werror && ./main
```

sanitizer detects memory leaks, 4 byte due to I add vector v = {1} to class G. Without this vector it works normally. Tell me please what is the problem, i dont understand.

I expected that that code will work normally. I expected that vector v will be destructed by standard destructor.

Comment: You create six instances of `G` but only destroy five. What exactly are you trying to accomplish?  If you want to replace the first element of the array with a "fresh" object, then `t[0] = G();`.

Comment: Looks like you are playing around with [Placement New](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new#Placement_new). It's a bit tricky, so definitely read the linked documentation.

Comment: What do you want this code to do? Why did you write it?

Comment: Your question has been answered. Please make sure to *accept* it,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`G* t = new G[5];` constructs 5 `G` with vectors `t[0]`..`t[4]`.

`new (t) G();` constructs a new `G` and its vector at `t[0]` again, without destroying the previously constructed `G` object and its vector at that storage.  You need to destroy the old objects before overwriting them:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
using namespace std;

class G {
public:
    vector<int> v = {1};
};

int main() {
    G* t = new G[5];
    t[0].~G(); // <-- add this
    new (t) G();
    delete [] t;
}
```